# How to return a JWTtoken when users registers for the first time in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I pretty new to Springboot with jwt,  I need to generate a jwt token when users sign up for the first time and use the token to allow redirect to another page instead of returning user registered successfully message. How can I achieve this? I am able to generate a token when users signin and use the token for authentication. any help will be appreciated.

how am generating on signin method

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                                                 userDetails.getId(), 
                                                 userDetails.getUsername(), 
                                                 userDetails.getEmail(), 
                                                 roles));
    }
```

my signup method.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {

        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                             encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()),signUpRequest.getFirstname(),
                signUpRequest.getSurname(),signUpRequest.getTelephoneno(),
                signUpRequest.getWhatsappno());

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
        //return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt);
    }
```

how can I generate a token when users sign instead of `return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));`

Comment: A common practice is redirect the user to login page after register process, showing a message like "User registered successfully, please login!" #1 Why do you need a token in this step?

Comment: so it is not recommended?